# Is it possible to control the content on Developer Portal in Azure API Management based on role user?

Tags: azure-api-management, apim

I want to control the content on the Developer Portal on Azure API Management base on role user

Comment: I never saw such a thing. The content is defined in OpenApi and there are no roles.

Answer (score 1):

We have the RBAC roles in Azure API Management (APIM) for giving permissions like Read-only access to services and entities of APIM, managing the developer portal of APIM.

Even we can restrict the users from the APIM Instance APIs based on User Access Control in the Products, Subscriptions Level available in the APIM Developer Portal.

Refer to this [MSFT Article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/usage-of-custom-rbac-roles-in-azure-api-management/ba-p/1560571) for more information.